# Apache Camel HTTP display request and response

Tags: https, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to load data from CSV file to a webservice. Is there anyway I can display request and response. Below is the route configuration..

I split and aggregate 100 items from array to be sent as POST body.

```
from(fileLocation)
.unmarshal().csv().bean(new CSVConverter(), "process")

.split(body())
.aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(100)
.completionTimeout(1000)
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)

.setHeader("Authorization", simple(apiKEY))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(apiURL))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
.to("https://serivceurl.com/abc");
```

Please let me know how can I display request and response with above route?

Answer (score 2):

You can use camel log component to log headers; properties and body

ex:

```
.to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
.to("https://serivceurl.com/abc");
.to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
```

For more options pl refer: https://camel.apache.org/log.html

If you are planning to use CXF to invoke web service, out of the box logging feature can be used as below,

```
<cxf:bus>
  <cxf:features>
    <cxf:logging/>
  </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Comment: Your 'to' URI is wrong according to the page that you linked to. What you have posted will produce an INFO level log message to the logging category 'DEBUG'. The correct format of the URI should be: `log:some.log.category?level=DEBUG&showBody=true&showHeaders=true`

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the `org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer` class you'll see that there is some logging implemented.

```
        try {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Executing http {} method: {}", method.getName(), method.getURI());
        }
        int responseCode = executeMethod(method);
        LOG.debug("Http responseCode: {}", responseCode);
```

So if you configure your logging framework (like logback) to the correct LoggingLevel you'll see what the HTTP-Component exactly does.
If you want to log it yourself you can try with the **log component** or the **log dsl** like mentioned in the other answer.