# How to define camel jetty routes for https request and pass the parameter to some api for authentication?

Tags: https, apache-camel, maven-jetty-plugin

I want to send https consumer request using camel-jetty component and that address returns some response in JSON format, below I mention my DSL code.

```
from("jetty:https://someSiteAddress.com/api/control/authorizeUser?username=__&password=__").to("stream:out"); 

I am getting this warning:  
[WARNING]   
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied  
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0 (Native Method)  
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind (Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind (Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind
```

But whenever I hit this HTTP URL in browser it will execute perfectly with authentication.
If anyone knows what to do to perform this action in apache camel please help me it will be very cheerful for me and others.

And how could I know which method camel using for sending a request like POST or GET.
 **Thank You**

Comment: Hi! If I understand correctly, you want to consume this endpoint: `https://someSiteAddress.com/api/control/authorizeUser?username=__&password=__`, correctly? If I'm right, you should use the `camel-http` component in `to`. The way your code is described, you are  **exposing** the URL, not consuming it. If you're having troubles with it, let me know that I put it in a answer.

Comment: @RicardoZanini Thank You for helping, Let me specify clearly Here I want to hit endpoint: from("mention above") which is return some token_Id's and these token_Id's I am printing on console by to("stream:out"). But I am getting above error and I think this error because of **jetty**.

Comment: Hi! please, see my answer. The way you are using jetty is to expose a endpoint at this address: `https://someSiteAddress.com` not consuming from it. To consume from an url you have to specified it using `to()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this instead? I'll comment each line to help understand your problem.

```
// endpoint to start your route. could be a http endpoint you expose via jetty, jms, vm, seda or any other option. Here I'm using the simplest one.
from("direct:start")
    // logs on
    .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    // consume the endpoint
    .to("https://someSiteAddress.com/api/control/authorizeUser?username=__&password=__"")
    // log the body to the console so you could process the response later knowing what to do (the token you are mentioning should be in here.
    .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    .to("stream:out") //or whatever you want to
```

Don't forget the `camel-http` dependency for this example to work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hello @RicardoZanini I appreciate for  clearing my concept,The code is ***Build Success*** but I am still not getting response(In form of token and id). just in case if you have doubt on my ***URL response*** it is working fine in browser.

Comment: @RajatTemaniya please post the response you are viewing in browser. The response body should be in your response.

Comment: Hello @RicardoZanini  this what I am looking for ***{"organizationPartyId":"MY_COMPANY","sessionId":"somerandomid.jvm1","_LOGIN_PASSED_":"TRUE","authorizeUserResult":{"userLoginId":"myuser","responseMessage":"success","partyId":"myparty","token":"mytoken=="}}***
I tried to get in exchange but no response.

Comment: This is awkward. Maybe you are having problems with TLS/SSL. It’s possible to try with an endpoint non HTTPS?

Comment: There is any other way in camel where I can get response in exchange body.

Comment: Hello @RicardoZanini  how do I know the camel is connect the given URL

Comment: You could inspect the logs. I've updated my answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651918/apache-camel-http-display-request-and-response

Comment: Why it is not coming directly inside the exchange body via processor ?

Answer (score 0):

This is also working fine.

```
  from("direct:in")
 .to("https://www.someAddress.com/api/control /authorizeUser?username=__ &password=__")
 .to("stream:out");
```

Thanks  @RicardoZanini